# Question on sequences and induction

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to show that $a_n$ is increasing where $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}$ = $ \sqrt{a_n+2}$

I proceeded by induction so showed that $a_{n+1}>a_n$ for all n greater than 1
So I showed it was true for n=1

Then assumed $a_{k+1}>a_k$ for some k greater than 1

Then I add two to both sides and square root to show it's true for k+1.

So $a_{k+1}+2>a_k+2$

$ \sqrt{a_{k+1}+2}> \sqrt{a_k+2}$

Which is $a_{k+2}>a_{k+1}$
So is this ok to show this statement?

Also how would you show that a_n has a limit and compute $lim_na_n$

I think to compute the limit you need to prove that if $b_n$ goes to b then $ \sqrt{b_n+2}$ goes to $ \sqrt{b+2}$  thank you for your help.

Comment: Your argument is incorrectly structured. You prove it for $n = 1$, then, assuming it is true for $n$, show it is true for $n + 1$.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly :)

Comment: Ok, I don't understand is that not what I have done

Comment: Hi, could you edit your question to make it a little clearer by including some of the steps, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If
$a_{n+1}
=\sqrt{a_n+2}
$
then
$a_{n+1}^2
=a_n+2
$
so
$a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2
=a_n+2-a_n^2
=-(a_n^2-a_n-2)
=-(a_n-2)(a_n+1)
$.

Therefore,
if $0 < a_n < 2$
then
$a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2
\gt 0$
since
$a_n-2 < 0$
and
$a_n+1 > 0$.

Also,
if $0 < a_n < 2$
then
$\sqrt{a_n+2}
\lt \sqrt{4}
= 2$.

For $a_1 = 1$
we have
$a_n$ increasing and bounded
so $a_n \to L$
for some $1 < L \le 2$.

Therefore
$L^2 = L+2$
so
$L = 2$
or
$L = -1$.

Since $L > 1$,
we must have
$L = 2$.

More generally,
if
$a_{n+1}
=\sqrt{a_n+k}
$
then
$a_{n+1}^2
=a_n+k
$
so
$a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2
=a_n+k-a_n^2
=-(a_n^2-a_n-k)
$.

This factors if
$1+4k$
is a square,
$(2d+1)^2 = 4k+1$
(since $4k+1$ is odd).
The roots of
$x^2-x-k = 0$
are then
$\dfrac{1\pm (2d+1)}{2}
=\dfrac{2d+2, -2d}{2}
=d+1, -d
$.

Therefore
$a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2
=-(a_n^2-a_n-k)
=-(a_n-d-1)(a_n+d)
$.

If $0 < a_n \le d+1$
then
$a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2
\gt 0$
since
$a_n-d-1 < 0$
and
$a_n+1 > 0$.

Also,
if $0 < a_n < d+1$
since
$(2d+1)^2 = 4k+1$
so that
$k = d^2+d$,
then
$\sqrt{a_n+k}
\lt \sqrt{d+1+d^2+d}
= \sqrt{d^2+2d+1}
= d+1$.

For $0 < a_1 \lt d+1$
we have
$a_n$ increasing and bounded
so $a_n \to L$
for some $1 < L \le d+1$.

Therefore
$L^2 = L+k$
so
$L = d+1$
or
$L = -d$.

Since $L > 0$,
we must have
$L = d+1$.

For the original problem,
$k=2$ gives
$d=1$.

Comment: Hi tha k you. Why do you only consider an from 0 to 2?

Comment: Because if $a_n > 2$ then $2 < a_{n+1} < a_n$.

Comment: So does that show an is increasing or are you assuming it

Comment: The increasing or decreasing of $a_n$ follows from $a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2
=a_n+2-a_n^2
=-(a_n^2-a_n-2)
=-(a_n-2)(a_n+1)
$.

Answer (score 0):

First consider that $a_n$ may have a limit $L$. If $L$ exists then $L=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt {2+a_n}\,=\sqrt {2+L}. $

So if $a_n$ is strictly increasing with $a_1=1$ and if $L$ exists then $0<L=\sqrt {2+L}\,$ so $L=2.$ So prove that $2>a_{n+1}>a_n >0$ for all $n$ by induction:

(i). We have $2>a_1>0.$

(ii). If $2>a_n>0$ then $4>2+a_n>0$ so $2>\sqrt {2+a_n}\,=a_{n+1}>0$. So $2>a_n>0$ for all $n$ by induction.

(iii). Since $a_{n+1}>0$ by (ii), we have $a_{n+1}>a_n\iff a_{n+1}^2>a_n^2\iff 2+a_n>a_n^2,$ and we do have $2+a_n>a_n^2$ when $2>a_n>0.$ So $a_{n+1}>a_n$ for all $n$ by induction.

So $a_n$  is strictly increasing and is bounded above by $2$ so it has a  limit $L$. And by the first paragraph, $L=2.$

BTW, in (iii), if $2>a_n>0$ then $2+a_n>a_n+a_n=(2)(a_n)>(a_n)(a_n)=a_n^2.$